# Has Quran ordered us to read from it in Salat?

Tags: quran, salat

In a TV show, I heard it's an order of the Quran itself that we have to read parts of it in Salat.

I searched with these key phrases and could not find this order:

- What the Quran says about Salat?
- Orders of the Quran considering Salat.

Has Quran ordered us so? In what chapter what verse?

Comment: The Quran talks about Salah in a very passing manner, as if how to do Salah is already known to the reader.

Comment: @The Z, your point makes a sense. We know that prayer was obligatory in the sunnah of the previous prophets.

Comment: @Muslim That can't be the reason because Allah also says they did not know how to pray before he taught them

Answer (score 2):

Yes, however mainly in verses in the context of the recommended night prayer (maybe because this was the first kind of prayer practiced in Islam as mentioned by many scholars) for example it is mentioned in [surat al-Isra'a](https://legacy.quran.com/17/78-79)

> Establish prayer at the decline of the sun [from its meridian] until the darkness of the night and **[also] the Qur'an of dawn. Indeed, the recitation of dawn is ever witnessed.** (78). And from [part of] the night, **pray with it** as additional [worship] for you; it is expected that your Lord will resurrect you to a praised station.

The first verse is mentioning prayers and the Qur'an recitation at dawn and its virtuous, and the second verse says pray with such a recitation at night too.
Both essentiell verbs here appear in imperative:

> أقم الصلاة
> Establish prayer!

And

> قرآن الفجر ... فتهجد به
> The recitation of (the Qur'an at) dawn ... pray with it (at night)!

imperative in Arabic means "أمر" which literally means "order", however based on the interpretation it could also mean a recommendation. Therefore reciting qur'an after al-Fatihah in the prayer is regarded as sunnah by scholars.

Comment: This verse does not order *to read the Quran in Salat*. It just says *read the Quran*. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati it says establish prayer

Comment: The verbs in this sentence are imperative so it is understood as an order

Comment: I don't see `Recite Quran in Salah` in this translation. And different translations are saying diffirent things.

Comment: According to [corpus.quran.com](https://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=17&verse=79) `with it (bihi)` refers to night prayer.

Comment: @Muslim this doesn't make sense because Qur'an القرآن is masculine, and prayer.as-Salat الصلاة Is feminin in Arabic and bihi به refers to something masculine, if the reference was to a prayer it would have been  بها. While bihi here means by the recitation if Qur'an, as the whole second sentence (verse) is referring to the prior verse (because of the beginning letter And و).